# python: win32com and cx_Freeze - error

Tags: python, win32com, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile a Python 3.3 script using cx_Freeze.
The script uses win32com.client to control [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/). This works perfect when I directly run it. But when I compile it, it throws this exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\Python\3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    sdb = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("SongsDB.SDBApplication", MMEventHandler)
  File "O:\Python\3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 260, in
 DispatchWithEvents
    clsid = disp_class.CLSID
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CLSID'
```

It doesn't even work when I try to compile a really short script which uses `win32com.client`:

```
import win32com.client

class MMEventHandler:
    pass

sdb = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("SongsDB.SDBApplication", MMEventHandler)
```

And this is my setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ['win32com', 'shlex', 'os', 'pythoncom', 'base64', 'tornado']
filename = "test.py"
setup(
    name = 'Test',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'test',
    author = 'no',
    author_email = 'someting@my.org',
    options = {'build_exe': {
        'excludes':excludes,
        'packages':packages,
        'includes':includes
        }},
    executables = [Executable(filename, base = None, icon = None)])
```

Comment: Is it the same error that you get from your short example script?

Comment: [This message](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=25457945) suggests that you need to include the `win32com.gen_py` package when you freeze it. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, it's the same error.

Comment: I included the whole `win32com` package but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm going to look into this - could you put the output from freezing it in a pastebin somewhere?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mKyNJRCv and I added the setup.py script to the question.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. I 'fixed' cx_Freeze to ignore modules which don't have a valid Python name, but it looks like win32com relies on some like that. Do you have .py files with dashes in the name in `O:\Python\3\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\` ? If so, try using the previous release [from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.1/) and see if that works any better.

Comment: Yes, there is a `E602ED16-8EF9-4F08-B09F-6F6E8306C51Bx0x1x0.py`. I downgraded cx_Freeze, but it still doesn't work. Same error as before.

Comment: Can you post the log from freezing with cx_Freeze 4.3.1?

Comment: No idea why, but after I restarted my PC this morning it worked with 4.3.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting as an answer, to summarise:

For cx_Freeze 4.3.2, I made a change so that it would only copy modules with names which are valid Python identifiers (so they can be imported). However, win32com appears to rely on modules such as:

```
win32com\gen_py\E602ED16-8EF9-4F08-B09F-6F6E8306C51Bx0x1x0.py
```

The hyphens (`-`) in the filename make it not a valid Python identifier, so it doesn't get copied. I've [opened an issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/44/win32com-relies-on-modules-with-non) for cx_Freeze. In the meantime, a workaround is to downgrade to cx_Freeze 4.3.1, which you can download [from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/files/4.3.1/).

Also, I think that these modules are generated when you first wrap a COM object. So make sure that you run your code before freezing it.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? cx_Freeze is on 4.3.4 now. Would I still need to go back to 4.3.1 if having this same problem? I found I could fix the problem if I run the python script on local machine first, and then freeze, and then copy the .py file(s) with the dashes to the correct library.zip folder and re-zip it.

Comment: It [got fixed](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-requests/79/re-allow-including-modules-with-non/diff), but there hasn't been a release of cx_Freeze since then. You could install cx_Freeze from the development version.