# How to enforce ealry-binding with cx_freeze and win32com?

Tags: python, win32com, cx-freeze, late-binding, early-binding

I made some python scripts to control an external CATIA application. I now have to package those scripts into executable files but i can't manage to do it.

### Question :

*How to enforce win32com to use early binding for specific modules once scripts are built ?*

---

### Details :

My scripts controls a CATIA application using **win32com.client** module. I handle CATIA with late binding except the module *CATIA V5 SpaceAnalysisInterfaces Object Library* that contains functions with reference input/output arguments. For this one i use early binding, sadly the simple use of **MakePy** wasn't enought, i had to modify generated sources from the **win32com.gen_py** package to obtain a correct behavior from the input/output arguments. Now it works fine when i execute python scripts. But if i build them using either **py2exe** or **cx_freeze** the executable uses only late-binding so i get bad results.

Here's the way that i hook CATIA application and use its API :

```py
import win32com.client

buff = [0, 0, 0]

catApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application") # Late bind needed
doc = catApp .Documents.Open(path)
part = doc.Part # This property fails if using early binding
spa = doc.GetWorkbench(u"SPAWorkbench")

I = spa.Inertias.Add(part) # Early bind needed

cogCoords = I.GetCOGPosition(buff) # The damn input/ouput argument function
```

And here's my build script using **cx_freeze** :

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {
    "includes": [],
    "excludes": [],
    "packages": ["win32com.gen_py"]
    }

target = Executable(
    script = "test.py",
    base = "Console",
    compress = True,
    icon = None,
    )

setup(
    name = "Test",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Early Binding Test Built",
    author = "C.LECLERC",
    options = {"build_exe": options},
    executables = [target]
    )
```

This build script generate a bunch of files including the content of my actual **win32com.gen_py** module so it should works. But when i execute the file it uses only late binding. I couldn't check if the files are correctly added when i use **py2exe** but the behavior is exactly the same : **late bind !**

---

I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662605/python-win32com-and-cx-freeze-error) but my problem is different. Modules are correctly copied and scripts doesn't raise exceptions. The input/output functions just doesn't works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question to share the solution i found and flag the problem as resolved.

### Solution :

Just copy the *'dicts.dat'* file from the **win32com.gen_py** package to the equivalent folder of the *'library.zip'* archive generated by cx_freeze.

Comment: Thanks, I've made a note of this [on a cx_Freeze issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/44).